# notification based on status OPEN from the database asp.net

Tags: asp.net

[complaint status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hPB.png)Hi m currently working on complaint management system using bootstrap asp.net c# and sql . i want to get notification alert in my website based on pending or OPEN complaints status . please help me guys.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hPB.png)
This is pic of my sql table

Comment: SignalR probably will help you, if you want to receive notification on client side. If not - please clarify your requirements by using of code/data samples

Comment: when ever i log in i want an alert or notification stating that THE COMPLAINT IS STILL OPEN